# How do you send an email in Shopware 6 controller?

Tags: php, symfony, email, e-commerce, shopware

In Shopware 5 there was a `mail->send()` function which was sending an email with the desired template and content.
What is the name of the function in Shopware 6?

P.S. I see some files which I think are the ones needed, some examples of mail sending would be welcomed.

```
Shopware\Core\Content\MailTemplate\Service\MessageFactory.php
Shopware\Core\Content\MailTemplate\Service\MailSender.php
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Within Shopware 6 you also have the Mailservice which provides you a [send() method](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/dfe0ca65cfb3a55a0ea1e3f8ab34f6a559f07525/src/Core/Content/MailTemplate/Service/MailService.php#L109).

So basically a really simple example to use the service would be:

```
public function __construct(
    MailServiceInterface $mailService,
) {
    $this->mailService = $mailService;
}

private function sendMyMail(SalesChannelContext $salesChannelContext): void
{
    $data = new ParameterBag();
    $data->set(
        'recipients',
        [
            'foo@bar.com' => 'John Doe'
        ]
    );

    $data->set('senderName', 'I am the Sender');

    $data->set('contentHtml', 'Foo bar');
    $data->set('contentPlain', 'Foo bar');
    $data->set('subject', 'The subject');
    $data->set('salesChannelId', $salesChannelContext->getSalesChannel()->getId());

    $this->mailService->send(
        $data->all(),
        $salesChannelContext->getContext(),
    );
}
```

Make also sure to tag the service within your `services.xml`.

```
<service id="Your\Namespace\Services\YourSendService">
  <argument id="Shopware\Core\Content\MailTemplate\Service\MailService" type="service"/>
</service>
```

**Email Template**

If you want to use Email Templates, there is also a how-to add a mail template in a plugin

If you have an email template, you need to fetch it before sending the email. Then you're able to get the content from your email template to pass those values to the `send()` method.

```
private function getMailTemplate(SalesChannelContext $salesChannelContext, string $technicalName): ?MailTemplateEntity
{
    $criteria = new Criteria();
    $criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('mailTemplateType.technicalName', $technicalName));
    $criteria->setLimit(1);

    /** @var MailTemplateEntity|null $mailTemplate */
    $mailTemplate = $this->mailTemplateRepository->search($criteria, $salesChannelContext->getContext())->first();

    return $mailTemplate;
}
```

You can later than set those Email values which are coming from your Email template (which is also available within the administration ) instead of hardcoding it within your send method.

```
$data->set('contentHtml', $mailTemplate->getContentHtml());
$data->set('contentPlain', $mailTemplate->getContentPlain());
$data->set('subject', $mailTemplate->getSubject());
```

Comment: I did it exactly the same way as you did but nothing happened! The profiler says, that I have 1 Message in spool. If I test my connection with console command swiftmailer:email:send the mail received at the same time I pressed enter. When I registered to the shop, the mail appears immediately. When I try to commit the spool with swiftmailer:spool:send it says:  0 emails sent. What do I wrong and why is there no documentation of using the pool? Can somebody help me?

Comment: The codes here are correct,@ThomasDeutschländer it may be because of wrong email configuration.

Comment: You may check out this link also:
https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-send-a-custom-email-in-shopware-6/